# how to search an element from a file in c

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

My code needs to do three things:

- Read numbers from a file `FILE1` into an array (dynamic)
- Sort those numbers
- Search for numbers input from a `FILE2` in the sorted array.

.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fp1 = fopen ("myFile1.txt", "r");
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        printf ("cannot open this file");
        exit (0);
    }
    FILE *fp2 = fopen ("test1.txt", "w");
    if (fp2 == NULL) {
        puts ("Not able to open this file");
        exit (1);
    }
    int i = 0, num, j, k;
    int *B = NULL;
    int *C;
    int a;
    int size = 32;

    B = malloc (sizeof (int) * size);

    while (fscanf (fp1, "%d", &num) == 1) {
        if (i < size) {
            B[i] = num;
            fprintf (fp2, "%d\r\n", num);
            i++;
        }
        else {
            C = malloc (sizeof (int) * 2 * size);
            memcpy (C, B, size * sizeof (int));
            free (B);

            B = &C[0];
            B[i] = num;
            i++;
            size = size * 2;
            i++;

            for (j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
                for (k = j + 1; k < size; ++k) {
                    if (B[j] < B[k]) {
                        a = &B[j];
                        B[j] = B[k];
                        B[k] = a;
                    }
                }
            }
            printf ("after sorting");
            for (j = 0; j < size; ++j)
                printf ("%d\n", B[j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
    fclose (fp1);  /* note this code is never reached */
    fclose (fp2);
}
```

I successfully complete the first part of reading in the numbers from a file.  But I am not able to understand how to sort these numbers.

I am trying to apply bubble sort, but it puts `0`s in my array.  How is my implementation incorrect?

Comment: a= &B[j]; here a is an int but &B[j] is an int*

Answer (score 1):

`&` is  the address-of operator. You pass it as a pointer. You need `a = B[i]`, since `a` is an `int`.

Now you sort the numbers descending, if you want them to be ascending change the `<` to `>` in if `(B[j] < B[k])`.

Also you must **always** check whether `malloc` succeeded or not with e.g.:

```
if (!B) {
    fprintf(stderr,"B alloc error");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Also you might want to consider `realloc`.

In addition there is a built-in `qsort` in `stdlib.h`, which gives much better time than `O(n^2)`.

*Note:* I haven't tested your file operations, since you said they work properly.

Comment: @Trisha After viewing some of your previous questions, I recommend you reading Kernighan & Ritchie's "The C Programming Language" as a introductory/reference book. More precisely Ch. 5 (pointers) & 6 (structs and allocs).

Comment: Technically `'&'` is the urnary *address-of* operator which returns the *address of* an object. `'*'` is the dereference operator which provides the value at a pointer address (dereferences one-level of pointer indirection)

Comment: Good job. Just wanted to make sure that was cleaned up. I generally don't like people editing my answers, so I left that to you to do.